# Write and play media from phone memory using Android media player

Tags: java, android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, file-transfer

I'm trying to get an mp3 file and save it on the phone memory not the SD card then play it immediately with the Media Player. This code worked well when I used it to do the same thing on the SD card previously so it seems there may be some mistakes in the location where I save and read the mp3.

Here is my code:

```
try {

            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            URI uri = null;
            try {
                uri = new URI(
                        "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl="
                                + oLanguage + "&q=" + text);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String FileName = "Audio2.mp3";
            URL u = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

//          FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(
//                  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//                          + "/download/" + FileName));

            FileOutputStream f = openFileOutput(FileName, MODE_PRIVATE);                
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();

//          player.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
//                      + "/download/" + FileName);

            player.setDataSource("/data/data/com.comm/files/" + FileName);              
            player.prepare();
            player.start()
```

Logcat:

```
        07-30 12:23:47.319: W/MediaPlayer(22426): info/warning (1, 26)
    07-30 12:23:47.319: E/MediaPlayer(22426): error (1, -4)
    07-30 12:23:47.319: W/System.err(22426): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at com.comm.Connect.Text(Connect.java:396)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at com.comm.Connect$7.onClick(Connect.java:233)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    07-30 12:23:47.329: W/System.err(22426):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And finally do I need to specify any permissions to allow me save to the phone memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research it seems I needed to use I found I needed to use an input stream the code below solved the problem

```
        FileOutputStream f = null;
            try {
                f = openFileOutput(FileName, MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();

            player = new MediaPlayer();
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.comm/files/"+ FileName);
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
            fis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things :

1. What does the outer catch look like? Make sure you're doing
   something useful such as catching the exception and spitting the
   stack trace out, that'll be much more use and should give you a more
   descriptive error
2. If you're trying to write anything to disk, make sure you have
   `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your [manifest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) file

Try and get us a stack trace, that will help **us** help **you**

Comment: I already have the permission. I've updated my question to show output from logcat